# Does second-order-arithmetic + PD proof consistency of ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Second-order-arithmetic augmented with the axioms of projective determinacy seems to be quite a strong theory.

Does this system proof the consistency of ZFC or better ZFC + some large cardinals?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, second-order arithmetic plus PD proves the consistency of ZFC plus a good supply of large cardinals. If I remember correctly, it's equiconsistent with ZFC plus the existence of $n$ Woodin cardinals for all (really) finite $n$.